# curl_exec return false after upgrading PHP form 5.4 to 5.5

Tags: php, curl, php-5.5

I upgraded php version from 5.4 to 5.5. After upgrading php curl_exec function start to return **false**. Are there any changes about curl options in php 5.5? I can't find anything in documentation.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); 
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 ); 
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::URL ); 
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );  
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90 );
        $data = curl_exec( $ch );
```

**PHP Version:** 5.5.14-2

**Note:** I get this error on Vagrant Box

Comment: what php version are you using exactly?

Comment: I added php version info to question @gries

Comment: have you tried using true instead of 1 as an argument for CURLOP_RETURNTRANSFER ?

Comment: Is curl installed on the VargantBox? Is it enabled for the PHP Install?

Comment: see your php.ini phpinfo(); on a empty .php and see if Curl is enabled. Are you doing this on windows?

Comment: Do curl_error() or curl_errno() display any error if called after curl_exec()?

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: You can try checking the info for a specific transfer `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

I've been through a similar php upgrade recently, also on a vagrant box, and the code snippet above appears to work ok when I try it here.

Rather than an issue with curl after the upgrade, is it possible that the upgrade has had an impact on the data going in to curl? Either the way `self::URL` or `$postData` get built - do they still contain the data you're expecting to see?

If those vars are still populating as you'd expect, then you can get more info from curl itself on what went wrong during the `curl_exec` by using [`curl_getinfo`](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), [`curl_errno`](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) and [`curl_error`](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();
...
$data = curl_exec( $ch );
if (!$data) {
    echo curl_getinfo( $ch ) . "\n";
    echo curl_errno( $ch ) . "\n";
    echo curl_error( $ch ) . "\n";
}
```

These lines should give you a more detailed report of what's going wrong since the upgrade.